# Finding all horisontal planes tangent to a surface

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

> A plane is horisontal when $z = a$, where $a$ is a constant.
>   Which values for $a$ makes $z = a$ describe a plane tangent to the surface given by $$ z = xye^{-\frac{9x^2+8y^2}{2}+1} ? $$

I computed the partial derivatives in the x- and y direction, and got that they are $0$ for $y = 0, x = 0, x=  \pm\frac {1}{3} $

Which only gives me the solution $z = 0$, which is not correct. (i.e $z = 0$ is not the only horisontal plane tangent to the surface).

Comment: I think you meant to have more than just a $-$ in the exponent. You solve this by enclosing whatever you want in curly brackets. `$e^-2$` gives $e^-2$ while `$e^{-2}$` gives $e^{-2}$. Or you can do what you have done.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the function
$$f(x,y):=\bigl(xe^{-9x^2/2}\bigr)(ye^{-8y^2/2}\bigr)\ ,$$
and compute
$$f_x=y(1-9x^2)\exp(\ldots),\qquad f_y=x(1-8y^2)\exp(\ldots)\ .$$
It follows that there are five critical points, namely
$$(0,0),\quad\left(\pm{1\over3}, \pm{1\over2\sqrt{2}}\right)\ ,$$
whereby the $\pm$s can be chosen independently.

Comment: How did you find the solution $ \pm \frac{1}{2 \sqrt2}$ ?